# vb.net Align one Sinlge Colum with Arabic String and Numeric Values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, arabic

I am coding in vb.net and using DataGridView.

I need to work with only one column which is in Arabic so I don't want my whole datagridview to use right to left text direction.

I just want one specific column to be adjusted to right to left text direction.

so far I am using this code

```
Private Sub gv_items_CellPainting(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles gv_items.CellPainting

    'This is for Arabic Text with Numeric Chars Alignments... AKA RTL for COL = 13 = Notes
    If e.ColumnIndex = 13 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, True)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.FormattedValue.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds, e.CellStyle.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft And TextFormatFlags.Right)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub gv_items_EditingControlShowing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles gv_items.EditingControlShowing

    'This is for Arabic Text with Numeric Chars Alignments... AKA RTL for COL = 13
    If (gv_items.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 13) Then
        e.Control.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
    End If
End Sub
```

this code works ok while I am editing the cell but once a cell is edited it doesn't show the Arabic text and numbers correctly.

Please have a look at this screenshot

[image: please have a look at this screenshot]

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `CellPainting` event for text alignment.
 DataGridView control has a specific property (`Alignment Enum`) for that, lets say that the column that you want to align to the right is the column in index 2 you can do that:

```
    ' Align all cells of column 2 to the right
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    ' alighn column header to the right
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
```

Comment: your solution didn't work because i need to set my Datagridview righttoleft RTF propery = True for one column if i set RTF property set to true then my whole datagridview components are drawn from right to left. i don't want that to happen.

Comment: its more like how the components are drawn. i need to show Arabic text mixed with the numeric chars and problem is that when the string is starting from Arabic text then mixed with numeric numbers its fine. but if i start the string from  lets sat "1 apple" then it comes "apple 1". i am not able to fix this issue without setting the whole DataGridView LeftToRight  property set to true. i was looking for one column solution rather than setting my whole DataGridView columns to RTL drawn.

Comment: if RTF is set to true the alignment  is inverted, try to set `Aligment` to `DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft`

Comment: i was looking for one column solution rather than setting the whole grid to RTL drawn. thanks for your time. appreciated :)